# Kubernetes /var/log/ is empty

Tags: kubernetes

I have my app deployed to Kubernetes and it's producing some logs. I can see the logs by running `kubectl logs -f <pod-id> -n staging`, but I can't find where the logs are physically located on the pod. The `/var/log/` folder is empty, and I can't find the logs anywhere else on the pod either.

Why is this happening, and where should the logs be?

Comment: The logs are located on the node where the pod is running on in folder /var/log/<pod_name>. Try to look on which node the pod is running first (kubectl get pods -o wide) . Then inside this node you can look at /var/log

Comment: @AchrafBentabib Hm, how can I SSH into the actual node?

Comment: What variant of Kube are you using?

Also its worth noting that sshing into workers is a bit of a anti-pattern. For info regarding how logging works in kube theres a bit of info [here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#how-nodes-handle-container-logs)

You should absolutely consider using something to persist logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ Achraf Bentabib  said

Kubernetes creates a directory structure to help you find logs based on Pods, so you can find the container logs for each Pod running on a node at

```
/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/
```

1. Identify the node on which the Pod is running:

   kubectl get pod pod-name -owide
2. SSH on that node, you can check which logging driver is being used by the node with:

If you are using docker then:

```
docker info | grep -i logging
```

If you are using kubernetes:

```
kubectl ssh node NODE_NAME
```

3. If the logging driver writes to file, you can check the current output for a specific Pod by knowing the container id of that Pod, to do so, on a control-plane node

   kubectl get pod pod-name ojsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[0].containerID}'

Example:

```
var/log/containers/<pod-name>_<namespace>_<container-name-container-id>.log -> /var/log/pods/<some-uuid>/<container-name>_0.log
```